# Getting HTML form values with JavaScript and saving them into JSON key and value pairs

Tags: javascript, html, json, electron

### Objective

`FrameWork used : ElectronJS`

I want to take the user submitted form, and use the NodeJS script to generate a `JSON` file on client PC. The json file will have `key and value pairs`.

Please see below for expected output.

### HTML

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="#">
<div class="form-group col-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account" name="account" placeholder="Enter Account" value="">
</div>
     <button type="submit" id="save" class = "btn text-white mb-0"> Save </button>
</form>
```

### JS

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', saveJSON(e))

async function saveJSON(e){

  e.preventDefault()

  var userData = document.getElementById('username').value
  var acctData = document.getElementById('account').value

  var formData = userData + acctData;
  console.log(formData);

  await writer.jsonWriter(formData);


//Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.
```

### Error

Here is the error I am facing
[image: Error]

### NodeJS Script

```
async function jsonWriter(data){

   let element = JSON.stringify(data);
   fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '\\data\\auth.json', element)

}

module.exports.jsonWriter = jsonWriter;
```

### Required Output

```
// auth.json

{"username":"Stack","account":"Overflow"}
```

Comment: `querySelector` is supposed to be using CSS selectors therefore it is not finding your elements. You may be better off using `document.getElementById()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I tried with ```getElementByID()```, it was the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there was an issue with how you were passing your event into your function and trying to call `preventDefault()`. I put your function directly on the event listener method with `async` keyword.

As previously mentioned, `document.querySelector()` uses CSS selectors unlike `document.getElementById()`. In your case I would stick with getting the input elements by their ID.

Like [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139957/6950859) said in his answer, you need a JavaScript object for [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to work properly.

```js
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  var userData = document.getElementById('username').value
  var acctData = document.getElementById('account').value

  var formData = {
    username: userData,
    account: acctData
  }; // create JS object
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
});
```

```html
<form id="form" method="POST" action="#">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
  <input type="text" id="account" name="account" placeholder="Enter Account">
  <button type="submit" id="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think that I can see your mistake.

In the Javascript you can change this part :

```
 var formData = userData + acctData;
 console.log(formData);
 await writer.jsonWriter(formData);
```

To this part :
Try to assign it to a javascript object like that :

```
var formData = {username: userData, account: acctData};
console.log(formData);
await writer.jsonWriter(formData);
```

it will stringify your object and write an appropriate output.

I think.

Comment: Thank you, but this problem still remains ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.saveJSON```